# Minor Bug in editing a proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, edits, rate-limiting

If I edit my Area 51 proposal and I exceed the limit of chars, I have to wait 30 seconds to try again.

For example, I edited my [Gardening](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1369/gardening-and-landscaping) Proposal to add landscaping.  When I was done I saved and was told I was over the 255 char limit.  So I deleted a sentence and saved again.  It then told me that I can only edit a post once every 30 seconds.

But I had not really edited my post.  At least this should be changed to say you can only **submit** an edit every 30 seconds.

Comment: The same thing happens with comments that are too short/long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. We now show character counters when editing proposals and questions, and submission is disabled if the input is too short or too long.